# Singleton database class : removing old query results

Tags: php, mysqli

I made a singleton database class for PHP. And i thought it was working great, but actually it isn't. Im now making a page that has 3 queries. 1 to check if an album exists,1 to check if a user owns an album, the other one gets the photos from the album.

Now in my third query i populate an object, however the results of the 1st 2 queries are also in that array so im getting notices!

Heres an example :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => My new album 1
        [slug] => my-new-album-1
        [user_id] => 1
        [views] => 0
        [datecreated] => 2013/03/23 16:00:43
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => My new album 1
        [slug] => my-new-album-1
        [user_id] => 1
        [views] => 0
        [datecreated] => 2013/03/23 23:51:58
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 117
        [title] => 
        [location_id] => 
        [date] => 2013-03-30 00:42:26
        [user_id] => 1
        [album_id] => 2
    )
```

And this is how i do a query and return the array :

```
mysqli_conn::getInstance()->query($sql)->all_assoc()
```

And this is the part of my database class that does the query and returns the results :

```
public function query( $sql ){

 $starttime = $this->time_to_float();        
 $this->query = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);          
 $endtime = $this->time_to_float();
 $exectime = ($endtime - $starttime);


 if (!$this->query){        
    throw new Exception(mysqli_error($this->connection));        
 } else {

    $this->arQueryLog[] = array ( 'query' => $sql, 
                                  'exectime' => $exectime, 
                                  'affected_rows' => mysqli_affected_rows($this->connection),
                                  'last_insert_id' => $this->lastID() );                                      


 }

 return $this;

}

public function all_assoc ()
{
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->query)){
        $this->result[] = $result;
    }

    return $this->result;

}
```

How can it is so only the last query results are in the result array?

Thanks!!

Comment: This is some very bad design you've got there. Why don't you just use the OOP version of `mysqli`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 major faults, irrelevant to database classes

- every variable have to be initialized before use. This code fails with it.
- PHP would even excuse the above fault if you were using a **local** variable for the local data

So, the right code have to be

```
public function all_assoc ()
{
   $result = array(); //initializing a local variable 
   while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->query)){
        $result[] = $result;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

and this all_assoc function better to be fed with $result variable instead of using a class property.

1 major fault relevant to database class.

- You aren't using placeholders, so, you have your queries vulnerable to SQL injection.

so, as you're already started for classes, take a look as [SafeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql). It will make your code shorter and safe.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing results to the result property of the class. Since it is a singelton, the previous values remain in the result property and everytime you call the all_assoc() method new result gets pushed in the property.

You should unset the result property in the all_assoc() method before pushing new results.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Jueecy might have a valid point in regards to the design, but since we don't have access to your full implementation, let's work with what we have.

Although it makes sense to store your database connection in a singleton, it is not really appropriate to store the query results in a singleton (and certainly not the database connection singleton) since you are very likely going to have more than one query per request.

From the code you've shared, my best suggestion is to simply return the `$query` value directly (without storing it on $this), and have `all_assoc()` (and related functions) accept `$query` and return `$result` directly (without storing it on $this).

You could create a `Query` class to wrap `$query` and a `Result` class to wrap individual result sets if you need to provide custom logic (aka the `exectime` and `arQueryLog` logic in your `query()` function), but you haven't provided any code that shows that to be necessary yet.

Good Luck,

-David Farrell